# Netlify - npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve

Tags: reactjs, npm, netlify

I am currently working on a project with GatsbyJS. I've installed contentful to it as a headerlessCMS and didn't have any issues. The site runs fine locally but when I try to deploy the site to Netlify I get this error:

```
    5:54:31 PM: Build ready to start
5:54:33 PM: build-image version: a49edbc55fc722f80f6b85963a5060f8d043a844 (focal)
5:54:33 PM: build-image tag: v4.8.1
5:54:33 PM: buildbot version: f89dd42aa70d76d1da992dc3fa004a4c745208bc
5:54:33 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
5:54:33 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
5:54:33 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
5:54:33 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
5:54:33 PM: git clone https://github.com/mont266/tw_react
5:54:34 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/main
5:54:34 PM: Parsing package.json dependencies
5:54:35 PM: Starting build script
5:54:35 PM: Installing dependencies
5:54:35 PM: Python version set to 2.7
5:54:36 PM: v16.15.1 is already installed.
5:54:36 PM: Now using node v16.15.1 (npm v8.11.0)
5:54:36 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
5:54:36 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
5:54:36 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
5:54:37 PM: Using ruby version 2.7.2
5:54:37 PM: Using PHP version 8.0
5:54:38 PM: No npm workspaces detected
5:54:38 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
5:54:38 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
5:54:38 PM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 8.11.0
5:54:38 PM: npm WARN config tmp This setting is no longer used.  npm stores temporary files in a special
5:54:38 PM: npm WARN config location in the cache, and they are managed by
5:54:38 PM: npm WARN config     [`cacache`](http://npm.im/cacache).
5:54:39 PM: npm WARN config tmp This setting is no longer used.  npm stores temporary files in a special
5:54:39 PM: npm WARN config location in the cache, and they are managed by
5:54:39 PM: npm WARN config     [`cacache`](http://npm.im/cacache).
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR!
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR! While resolving: react-owl-carousel3@2.2.5
5:54:42 PM: Creating deploy upload records
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR! node_modules/react
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.6 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @contentful/rich-text-react-renderer@15.12.1
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR!   node_modules/@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR!     @contentful/rich-text-react-renderer@"^15.12.1" from gatsby-source-contentful@7.14.0
5:54:42 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR!     node_modules/gatsby-source-contentful
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR!       gatsby-source-contentful@"^7.14.0" from the root project
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR!   22 more (@gatsbyjs/reach-router, @loadable/component, ...)
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR!
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-owl-carousel3@2.2.5
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR! node_modules/react-owl-carousel3
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR!   react-owl-carousel3@"^2.2.5" from the root project
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR!
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR! node_modules/react
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR!   peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-owl-carousel3@2.2.5
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR!   node_modules/react-owl-carousel3
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR!     react-owl-carousel3@"^2.2.5" from the root project
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR!
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR!
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR! See /opt/buildhome/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
5:54:42 PM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2022-06-20T16_54_39_021Z-debug-0.log
5:54:42 PM: Error during NPM install
5:54:42 PM: Build was terminated: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
5:54:42 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
5:54:43 PM: Finished processing build request in 10.014825654s
```

I have tried gatsby clean, I have tried deleting node_modules and reinstalling aswell as tried reinstalling legacy dependancies. There's no issues locally, would anyone be able to advise as to what might be causing this to not run on Netlify?

Thanks

Comment: are you able to build files on your local machine? if you run npm run build?

Comment: You’re probably running an older version of npm locally - update to the LTS version of node locally and then try npm install again. You’ll need to resolve the errors, as npm is now more strict instead of just giving warnings.

Comment: You can also just config the netlify build to use whatever version of node you have locally.